# Inserting for mysql with a loop like for or foreach -procedure

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have a lot of lines to add. I can do this by copying and pasting, but I have to write 25 * 30 = 750 lines of insert lines. Is there an easier way with the procedure? Thanks.

Example:

```
ids input varchar: 25,26,27,28

for 25 => ids[0]:
insert into (a,b,c) values ('y',ids[0],2);
insert into (a,b,c) values ('x',ids[0],2);
insert into (a,b,c) values ('z',ids[0],2);
insert into (a,b,c) values ('t',ids[0],2);

for 26 => ids[1]:
insert into (a,b,c) values ('y',ids[1],2);
insert into (a,b,c) values ('x',ids[1],2);
insert into (a,b,c) values ('z',ids[1],2);
insert into (a,b,c) values ('t',ids[1],2);
```

How can I solve it in the easiest way?

Note: I cannot use php. I have to do it on the database.

Comment: is this correct 4 times ids[0] then id 1,2,3,4

Comment: Sorry. I wrote it wrong. I fixed it. Thanks. @BerndBuffen

Comment: you forgot the tablename and do you want to store "ids[0]" or 25 for these id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

MariaDB has a sequell engine

```
INSERT INTO myTable (a,b,c) 
SELECT 
    ELT(zt.seq, 'y','x','z','t') AS a,
    r.seq AS b,
    2 AS c
    from seq_1_to_4 zt
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT * FROM seq_25_to_28) as r;
```

NOTE: You can also execute it without the INSERT line to see the output of the query